# Symfony2 - set security access_control to allow only authenticated anonymously

Tags: php, symfony, access-control, symfony-security

Let's say I have my `access_control` block under the `security.yml`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/reset-password, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

In this case everyone is alowed to enter `homepage` and `reset-password` pages. But I would like to allow these pages only for users authenticated anonymously. Fully authenticated users should get an `403 access denied error` or `404 page not found`.

According [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html#access-enforcement) with `allow_if` I should be ablo to create role expressions to define access. But if I do it like this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/reset-password, allow_if: "has_role('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY') and not has_role('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')" }
```

Now following the idea fully authenticated users (logged in) shouldn't be allowed to access the page and anonymously authenticated should be able to access, but, unfortunatelly, none of users are able to access it...

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you can test `IS_*` using `has_role()`? These act like roles but they're not roles. Maybe that's why it always returns `false`:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#checking-to-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-is-authenticated-fully

It seems like you should better use `is_anonymous()` and `is_authenticated()` custom functions in the `allow_if` expression.

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/expressions.html#security-expression-variables

Comment: Perfect it made it work just fine! `- { path: ^/reset-password, allow_if: "is_anonymous() and !is_authenticated()" }`